# Animate CC HTML5 - toggle fullscreen

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, animate-cc

I have this code (below) on a buton to force my HTML5 game to fullscreen, but I'd like to have it turn back also with the button - right now it only works using ESC key. Is it possbile?

```
this.fsbtn.addEventListener("click", doFullscreen);

function doFullscreen() {
    var i;
    var elem = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    var fs = ["requestFullscreen", "webkitRequestFullscreen", "mozRequestFullScreen", "msRequestFullscreen"];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (elem[fs[i]]) {
            elem[fs[i]]();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible. Change your `doFullscreen` function to a [toggle one](https://gist.github.com/demonixis/5188326) that checks if it's fullscreen or not:

```js
function toggleFullscreen(event) {
    var element = document.body;

    if (event instanceof HTMLElement) {
        element = event;
    }

    var isFullscreen = document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || false;

    element.requestFullScreen = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen ||           element.mozRequestFullScreen || function () {
        return false;
    };
    document.cancelFullScreen = document.cancelFullScreen || document.webkitCancelFullScreen ||           document.mozCancelFullScreen || function () {
        return false;
    };

    isFullscreen ? document.cancelFullScreen() : element.requestFullScreen();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation here for [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FUsing_full_screen_mode)

You can exit from fullscreen mode using functions listed below(for more read documentation)

[image]

In JS/HTML code you can add button with absolute position and high z-index. Write new click listener for added button and run cancelFullscreen function, that's all.

Example JS function for FullScreen mode:

```js
  function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
      if (videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        videoElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      }
    } else {
      if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        videoElement.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else {
        videoElement.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
    }
  }
```

Working example you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/fullscreen.html

Comment: I tried it like this, but I don't think I'm doing right... right!?


this.FS_1exit.addEventListener("click", exitFullscreen);

function exitFullscreen() {
    var i;
    var fs = ["webkitExitFullscreen", "mozCancelFullScreen", "msExitFullscreen"];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (elem[fs[i]]) {
            elem[fs[i]]();
            break;
        }
    }
}

Comment: I've edited the answer, see what the method above looks like

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it, but it gives me a "ReferenceError: videoElement is not defined". This actually looks like pure JS, which is a bit diferent than the JS used in Animate (but I don't enough to meddle and make it work... - unless I'm wrong...)

Comment: This is only example, adapt it to your needs